# Generate random int based on a 32 characters long string seed

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate a random seed based on a string value (which is ~32 characters long).

I don't want to use `string.GetHashCode()` since I may later will need a working implementation in another language (C++, Python, JavaScript) (Yes I will need to get rid of `Random()` too then and all other .NET classes).

I also want the whole input string to be relevant for the seed and not just a fraction of it.

This is the solution I came up with:

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G9Qr7r

I basically generate 8 `Random` instances with a Int32 seed based on a part of the SHA256 array. Everytime I generate a random number I switch to the next `Random` Instance.

code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography; 
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sha256Random rnd = new("Well, hello there");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(0,100));
        }
    }
}

public class Sha256Random
{
    private int[] seeds = default!;
    private Random[] rnd = new Random[8];
    
    private int rndIdx = 0;
    
    public Sha256Random(string seed)
    {
        GenerateSeeds(seed);
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        if(rndIdx>= 8)
            rndIdx=0;
            
        return rnd[rndIdx++].Next();
    }

    public int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        if (rndIdx >= 8)
            rndIdx = 0;

        return rnd[rndIdx++].Next(min, max);
    }

    public int Next(int max)
    {
        if (rndIdx >= 8)
            rndIdx = 0;

        return rnd[rndIdx++].Next(max);
    }

    private void GenerateSeeds(string value)
    {
        using var hash = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] bytes = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value));
        
        seeds = new int[bytes.Length/4];

        for (int i = 0; i < seeds.Length; i++)
        {
            int idx = i*4;
            seeds[i] = bytes[idx] | bytes[idx+1] << 8 | bytes[idx+2] << 16 | bytes[idx+3] << 24;
        }
        
        rnd = new Random[seeds.Length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < seeds.Length; i++)
        {
            rnd[i] = new Random(seeds[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like it's overengineered?!

Comment: If you want something simpler, maybe Donald Knuth’s multiplicative hash?

Comment: If I understood it correctly the Knuth hash generates a hash based on two integers. So basically I use it to generate a hash out of my 8 integers and then cast the uint to an int for use with `Random(int seed)` ... if so, I will check it out for sure :)

Comment: I made a small fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hEoVhm . Regarding collisions this could be more error prone I guess?

Comment: For future reference, unlike Stack Overflow we like to see as much code as possible, you have included the entire class, but the entire program in this case would give us more to review. It would be better if the using statements were also included.

Comment: I altered the question. I thought the fiddle link would suffice for instant testing :)

Comment: Can you make your requirements clearer? If you don't want to use GetHashCode() I don't see why it's ok to use Random. And what are the security needs? You are mixing a cryptographic-strength hash function with a weak Random implementation.

Comment: I want a RNG that takes every character of my seed string into account. It doesn't has to be secure in anyway. Maybe using sha256 is overkill and I should just use plain ASCII code (e.g. 4 characters = 1 integer seed for Random()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would prefer the simplest code that satisfies all of the criteria. In this case, that means having a single `Random` instance, initialized with `String.GetHashCode()`. I understand that `GetHashCode` isn't easily portable to other platforms, but neither is `Random`. If making it easily portable to other platforms becomes a requirement, you can replace them at that time. You might end up using SHA256 for that, and then that's one thing you wouldn't need to change, but it's also possible you would choose something else and need to change anyway.

As for the existing implementation, the seeds are only needed temporarily to initialize the `Random` instances and therefore should not be part of the object state. You have the value `8` hard-coded in several places, I would probably replace that with `rnd.Length`.

Getting further into matters of taste, I would prefer:

```
public int Next(int min, int max)
{
    rndIdx = (rndIdx + 1) % rnd.Length;
    return rnd[rndIdx].Next(min, max);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I think you forgot the paranthesises, should be `rndIdx = (rndIdx + 1) % rnd.Length;`

Comment: You're right. Updated.